understanding MIPS .align directive
I'm taking this architecture course, and I am struggling with .align directive.(https://i.sstatic.net/nNZXsCPN.png)
According to what I knew it aligns the fields after the directive to a multiple of 2 to the power of
n where n is the .ALIGN value. But here in my example it is not doing it. Why is this happening? Is there a specific reason for it?

Why do you think it's not doing it? You aligned A and its address in $t0 is 10010000. The directive applies only once so it will not align each word. Even if it did, you explicitly specify the offsets by doing e.g. 4($t0). Also note it's only a minimum alignment in case that's the source of your confusion.
